# ASP.NET MVC razor selectlist with datavalue/datatext from child object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an `IEnumerable<House>` collection, and each `House` object contains a `Room`. How can I use the data from `Room` object for datatext/datavalue in `SelectList` construction? I can write some extra code to generate the proper object with datatext/datavalue. But I just wanted to know if there's another way using razor only.

```
@Model IEnumerable<House>
@Html.DropDownList("", new SelectList(Model, ???, ???)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly me. here's my solution:

```
@Model IEnumerable<House> 
@Html.DropDownList("dropdown", new SelectList(Model.select(x => x.Room, "Height", "Width")
```